# Is there a way to make my cloud bucket content public to only my subscriber of my website?

Tags: url, google-cloud-storage

I have a website and I have stored certain files in google cloud bucket. I want the condition wherein the subscribers of my website have only access to the bucket (by clicking the url, which I will link in my website). Current problem is whenever anyone clicks the link in my website, it is directing to google.storeapis. So the user may feel that I have connected my website to another site.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you wanting to mask the URL or find a way to only allow certain users access to the bucket? Users seeing the GCP storage API in my opinion is fine. There are work arounds but you'll soon find the effort exceeds the reward. To allow only subscriber access it depends where the users are authenticated from. If you're using Google Identity platform, you could create a backend script to generate a SAS URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Ari. I am finding a way to allow users - who are subscribers of my website - to access the bucket. For example , suppose there is an image in my website and if the user clicks the image (linked with bucket url) , then they should read a file that I have stored in the bucket. The problem is , the url that is coming in the address bar after clicking the image is not of my domain name. Again thanks a lot for replying swiftly. Since I am not from the technology field, i have no idea of codes. (I have made the website using drag and drop features)

Comment: Right okay, I know what you mean, looks a little dirty. But its not uncommon and I'd only try and solve that issue if you find someone does complain. This guide might point you in the right direction, its definitely doable but might take a bit of learning https://medium.com/@marco_37432/create-a-custom-domain-cdn-with-google-beta-7ad9531dfbae

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.